# Spring security : Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having below code in `Myconfig` class which  extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I am getting statcktrace as  Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>        Expecting to only find a single bean for type interfacorg.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found [authenticationManagerBean, providerManager].

```
@Bean(name="preAuthFilter")
    public SSOCookieFilter preAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        SSOCookieFilter cookieFilter=   new SSOCookieFilter();
        cookieFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return cookieFilter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider getPreAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
         preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService());
         return preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

I have already tried few links from stackoverflow which suggested to have @qualifier but my bad it doesn't work(logically it should work as method name is considered as bean id).

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you overwrite authenticationManagerBean()?

Comment: if i comment it out  I am getting authentication manager muts be set  for my filter class that extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter class.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message indicates that a bean named `providerManager` bean is instantiated by Spring. Make sure you do not have any other `AuthenticationManager` classes annotated with `@Bean` or have them setup in your `xml` confiuration file.

Why do you `@Override` `authenticationManagerBean()`? If this method is already annotated with `@Bean` in the super class, this could be your problem.

Comment: If your code above extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` there should be no need to implement `authenticationManagerBean()` method, since you're only calling the super class, and are not applying any customization to the AuthenticationManager.

It's hard to tell what's going wrong, without knowing how your complete configuration is setup.

But based on the spring exception, you have a bean named `providerManager` defined somewhere, that is clashing with the other `AuthenticationManager`

Comment: @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
 public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider() {
  return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
 }
 
 @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
  return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

Comment: I am primarily struggling with this code. tried diff bean names and putting @qualifier

Comment: on changing method name and using @qualifier and changing bean names still getting the same exception

Comment: changing method names also dont work.people please help